# How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?

Tags: google-search, special-characters

I want to search for what `+=` means, but Google won't return any documents.

Also when I come across some PHP code I don't understand I can't search for the keywords as written.

How can I search for these special characters or include these special characters in a search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

Comment: You could search `+=` in Wikipedia.org.

Comment: Ironically, I distinctly remember many years ago that Google was cited for being _different_ in this respect, in that you could search for special characters and other programming symbols, because it was initially built with programmers in mind. The world was smaller back then. Ah, times change... *sigh*.

Comment: Did you try searching with double quotes like `"+="`. I did get back results for `+=` when I used Double quotes. https://www.google.com/search?q="+="

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Just announced by Google](https://blog.google/products/search/improvements-searching-special-characters-programming-languages/), searching for special characters is greatly improved.

The catch? You need to search for at least two or three characters.

> Now for queries containing sequences of 2-3 special characters such as [== vs ===] and [+=], Google will return results on the meaning of these sequences in programming languages.
>
> For example, if you’re searching for the meaning of [c++17], you will get results for the well-known programming language instead of c17, which brings up a Boeing airplane. Additionally, organization and product names that include punctuation, such as She++ and Notepad++, will return more accurate results.

`+=` is even called out specifically as an example string.

As with all Google improvements, this is likely rolling out in stages, and may not be available in all languages.

Comment: As of today, it's still not rolled out. Searching for `C++17` still gives results for `Boeing C-17 Globemaster III`.

Comment: Still doesn't work for `\\?\ `

Answer (score 27):

To this day, the search for that fairly distinct string produces no results in Google despite the existence of this answer and [the blog post](https://www.nu42.com/2012/07/what-is-f-in-perl.html) giving it context.

---

From https://superuser.com/revisions/16367/1

> ##### How do you google for "-f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%!"
>
> I came across this arcane bit of Perl:
>
> ```
> -f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%!
> ```
>
> Bonus points for explaining what it does.
>
> The question is, how can you search Google for this string?

---

#### Answer

Write it out:

**`-f`**: [perldoc -f -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). If no file name is specified (as is the case here) checks if `$_` contains the name of a plain file

**`>`**: Checks if the RHS is greater than the LHS

**`@+`**: In scalar context, returns the number of elements in `@+`

**`?`**: the conditional operator

**`*<`**: The glob for `main::<`

**`.`**: String concatenation operator

**`-&'_`**: Invokes a subroutine **`main::_`**. FYI, **`'`** is the `perl4` style package name separator. Try `perl -MHTML'Template -e 1`.

**`:`** : Continuing with conditional operator

**`$#`** : [The output format for printed numbers](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/rgs/pl-predef.html)

**`/`** : Division operator

**`%!`** : `%ERRNO`; see [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

So, it is not impossible to understand if you put a little effort into it. Clearly, this is not how anyone should write programs, but there some benefit from people pushing the boundaries.

Comment: Wow, bravo. I missed $# (deprecated?) and -&'_.

Comment: @Mark thanks. `$#` no longer exists. I do not know when it was phased out. Searching Google for http://www.google.com/search?q=perl4+%24%23 led me to it.

Comment: Neat, but could you clarify how does this help with searching for a keyword with special characters in Google Search? Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Originally, this question was posted to Stackoverflow with the title "How can I search for `"-f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%!"` on Google?` or something similar. Someone hastily decided the question was not a programming question, and it has been kicked around, changed, merged, morphed several times since then. My answer has moved around with it. See also [What is "-f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%!" in Perl?](http://www.nu42.com/2012/07/what-is-f-in-perl.html).

Comment: I came to this question because I'm trying to search for a different set of special characters, but saw this answer and was interested because I find Perl's wild syntax fascinating. So I read your answer and your blog post. To be perfectly honest: I still don't know what that code does! If you want your answer to be understandable by anyone who hasn't already been writing Perl for years, I think you would need to address order of operations and explain a few of the pieces some more. An example / summary / context for how the code might be used/useful would also be helpful!

Comment: @JakeRobb The code does not do anything useful and should not be used. It's an example of a line-noise looking sequence of characters that still turns out to be valid Perl with a not so subtle dig towards Perl's readability. But, this is an archeological discussion. Both the question and the answer should have remained on Stackoverflow where the context really was not about a practical way to search Google. But, that ship has sailed. To emphasize: **No one should write code like this in any language.**

Comment: Okay good, that makes me feel better! I figured that even terrible code like that was probably written for _some_ purpose. Guess not!

Answer (score 4):

https://duckduckgo.com handled my search for "Redis::Queue" properly (not ignoring `::`).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (the question is about Google). If you are recommending to use duckduckgo.com instead of Google you should elaborate on the reasons. Remember that answers should self contained. Ref. [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Ask a question about it on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) and wait for Google to index it.  I just found this page by googling `"-f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%!"` (with the quotes).

The resulting search page URL is `http://www.google.ca/search?q="-f>@%2B%3F*<.-%26'_:$%23/%25!"`

Answer (score 0):

I thought if you placed something in quotes it would force a search of that exact term.

ie searching for

> "C++"

would search for C++ and not just C

Comment: This is because the phrase `C++` is indexed specially. You actually don't need the quotes. See the [answer from Senseful](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search/1018#1018). So the `C++` gets valid hits for `C++` (not `C` and `C#`) because it is indexed, but `"1+2"` ignores the `+` and returns all that contain `1` and `2` because `1+2` is not indexed.

Answer (score -3):

It seems that almost no one has understood the ops question. He is not asking how to use `+=` as part of a Google search. He is asking how he might search for the definition of `+=` in a search engine that largely ignores special characters.

@ChrisF, you need to first understand what you're searching on in order to better phrase your query.

`+=` is a common assignment operator in almost any language. If you're specifically after a PHP definition then you might try `PHP assignment operators`. For string concatenation you would use `.=` which loosely translates to `and equals`.

For integers it would perform a mathematical operation. Refer [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) for more information.