# Hidden features of Google Search

Tags: google-search

What little known tips and tricks do you have for searching on Google?

---

> Please note that this question exists because it has a
>   high level of significance, but it is not
>   considered a good, on-topic question
>   for this site, so please do not use it
>   as evidence that you can ask similar
>   questions here. For more information, see the [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com//faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled list of answers:

- [Cheat Sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/804#804)
- [The ~ Operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/820#820)
- [Calculator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/2430#2430)
- [The OR operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search/2701#2701)
- [site:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/756#756)
- [define:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/762#762)
- [Time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/845#845)
- [The * Operator (Fill in the Blank)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/806#806)
- [Spell Checking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/2610#2610)
- [Flights](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/847#847)
- [allintext:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/1095#1095)
- [Movies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/801#801)
- [related:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/2174#2174)
- [Weather](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/4995#4995)
- [The - Operator (Exclude Terms)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/802#802)
- [Punctuation Notes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search/13479#13479)
- [Easter Eggs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search/1038#1038)

Comment: Unfortunately given the default accept behaviour, this answer is all the way on page three based on default vote sorting.

Answer (score 194):

I like, but rarely remember to use, the synonym operator.

Search for "~auto loan" will find info for both the word auto and its synonyms: truck, car, etc.

(example taken from Google's [cheat sheet](http://www.google.com/help/cheatsheet.html) of search operators)

Comment: I didn't know that Cheat Sheet existed!

Answer (score 83):

### The Calculator

Without a doubt. It's far more powerful than people realise (although people here have touched on some of its features).

**Basic maths**

```
3 * 2
```

Gives: [6](http://www.google.com/search?q=3%2A2)

```
4 + 12
```

Gives: [16](http://www.google.com/search?q=4%2B12)

It knows [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics):

```
2^10 / 4 + 1
```

Gives: [((2^10) / 4) + 1 = 257](http://www.google.com/search?q=%28%282%5E10%29+%2F+4%29+%2B+1)

It knows English:

```
(five plus seven) divided by six
```

Gives: [two](http://www.google.com/search?q=%28five+plus+seven%29+divided+by+six)

(I really like that it shows you its order of precedence, which can sometimes be confusing otherwise)

**Constants**

```
e
```

Gives: [2.71828183](http://www.google.com/search?q=e)

And so one with pi etc.

It also knows more complex expressions for constants:

```
Avogadro's number
```

Gives: [6.0221415 × 10^23](http://www.google.com/search?q=Avogadro%27s+number)

You can do maths with constants (and it knows imaginary numbers):

```
i^2
```

Gives: [-1](http://www.google.com/search?q=i%5E2)

```
e^(pi * i)
```

Gives: [-1](http://www.google.com/search?q=e%5E%28pi+%2a+i%29)

**Functions**

It can do logs:

```
log(16)
```

Gives: [1.20411998](http://www.google.com/search?q=log%2816%29)

I haven't found a way to directly take logs of arbitrary bases, but this work-around does me in the meantime:

```
log 1024 / log 4
```

Gives: [5](http://www.google.com/search?q=log+1024+%2F+log+4)

```
cos(pi)
```

Gives: [-1](http://www.google.com/search?q=cos%28pi%29)

**Dimensional Analysis**

It knows units! It can do conversion:

```
1 kilogram in lbs
```

Gives: [1 kilogram = 2.20462262 pounds](http://www.google.com/search?q=1+kilogram+in+lbs)

You can do maths with them of course. How many g's does the Bugatti Veyron pull if you floor it?

```
62 miles per hour / 2.5 seconds / 9.8 metres per second squared
```

Gives: [1.1312849](http://www.google.com/search?q=62+miles+per+hour+%2F+2.5+seconds+%2F+9.8+metres+per+second+squared)

Tasty. Want your output in a different form?

```
60 miles per hour * 20 minutes in kilometres
```

Gives: [32.18688 kilometres](http://www.google.com/search?q=62+miles+per+hour+%2F+2.5+seconds+%2F+9.8+metres+per+second+squared)

**Bases**

(Thanks to Dan's comment below)

The calculator can also output in other bases:

```
15 in hex
```

Gives: [15 = 0xF](http://www.google.com/search?q=15+in+hex)

```
12 * 3 in binary
```

Gives: [12 * 3 = 0b100100](http://www.google.com/search?q=12%2A+3+in+binary)

And it can convert from them too, and do Roman numerals!

```
XXXVI in decimal
```

Gives: [XXXVI = 36](http://www.google.com/search?q=XXXVI+in+decimal)

**Put it all together**

```
answer to life the universe and everything * pi * e * avogadro's number * speed of light
```

Gives: [6.47538066 × 10^34 m / s](http://www.google.com/search?q=answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything+%2A+pi+%2A+e+%2A+avogadro%27s+number+%2A+speed+of+light)

A more meaningful equation... how about how much energy a nuclear bomb releases? We all know E = mc^2:

```
600 milligrams * the speed of light squared
```

Gives: [5.39253107 × 10^13 joules](http://www.google.com/search?q=600+milligrams+%2A+the+speed+of+light+squared)

**Closing tips**

Sometimes you need to put in brackets to express precedence clearly, for example "five plus seven divided by six" and "(five plus seven) divided by six" give different answers.

If the calculator doesn't kick in you can attempt to coerce it by appending "=" to your query, for example "1+2=".

It knows most units and constants (including currencies) but it isn't 100% perfect, so if something doesn't work try rewording it.

Bonus tip for users of Chrome and Firefox: If you type a calculator query into the omnibar / search box and wait for suggestions to pop up, the first suggestion will be the answer. Saves you a pageload!

Lastly if you think it will work, it quite possibly will! It handles a wide array of inputs, outputs and operators, someone pointed me to [a comprehensive list here](http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html).

Comment: Excellent amount of detail :)

Comment: Thanks :) Most of that was off the top of my head, I use Google's calculator constantly as it's the only one I know of that does units.

Comment: It even understands bizarre units.  Try "1 m/s in furlongs per fortnight"

Comment: Short reference for the calculator: http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html

Comment: Longer reference: http://www.googleguide.com/calculator.html

Comment: Web interface to the calculator: http://www.soople.com/soople_intcalchome.php

Comment: 1 hellameter = 1.0 × 10^27 meters http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=0h&oq=hella&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGIH_enUS249US250&q=hellameters+to+meters

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: You can also get results in other number bases eg. '12 * 3 in roman numerals' or '10 ^ 2 in hex' or '1024 in binary' etc.

Comment: Linked the examples.

Comment: in addition to constants, [42](http://www.google.com.ph/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything)

Comment: I did actually sneak that one into the examples already, Reigel ;)

Answer (score 74):

### Easter Eggs

- [Searching for recursion](http://www.google.com/search?q=recursion) asks if you meant recursion :)
- [Pacman Game](http://www.google.com/pacman/) Featured on Google Search page.
- [the answer to life the universe and everything](http://www.google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything) results in: 42
- Type "[xx-hacker](http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=xx-hacker)" into search box and hit "I'm Feeling Lucky" (also xx-bork / xx-klingon / xx-piglatin)
- [Searching for anagram](http://www.google.com/#q=anagram) gives an interesting "did you mean?" suggestion
- [query for ASCII Art](http://www.google.ca/search?q=ascii+art) has an unexpected effect.
- searching for "[once in a blue moon](http://www.google.ca/search?q=once+in+a+blue+moon)" yields "1.16699016 × 10-8 hertz" (approximately once every 2.7 years)
- "[number of horns on a unicorn](http://www.google.com/search?q=number+of+horns+on+a+unicorn)" = 1
- "[the loneliest number](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=the+loneliest+number)"

Comment: That is a very cute Google'ism.

Comment: That's great!  B)

Comment: This is more of an Easter egg than a feature.

Comment: To me, it looks like a bug :D

Answer (score 73):

### site:

You can use the 'site:' keyword to make Google only return results from one site.

For example you could enter this into Google:

```
algorithms site:ocw.mit.edu
```

Which would bring you to results from ocw.mit.edu only.

You can also put quotes around your search terms to search for an exact string.

For example

```
"stackoverflow.com is great"
```

would yield different results from

```
stackoverflow.com is great
```

You can search specific sites for information by using:

```
site:yoursitehere.com searchterms
```

This works to the point where you can narrow your site search down to specific sub-folders, by using:

```
site:yoursitehere.com/folder1/folder2/ searchterms.
```

If you don't put 'site: before the yoursitehere.com then it just searches for occurrences of the URL name, and not necessarily the site itself.

Comment: the 'site:' modifier is one of my favs. Especially for sites that have sucky or no internal search engines.

Comment: You don't have to include an entire domain either. I use that regularly for country-specific searches: `site:.ch` (one reason I don't like .com for local companies)

Comment: I often use `site:stackoverflow.com` when a Google result doesn't have the answer to my question in the top few. :)

Answer (score 66):

### Conversions

Currency conversions and unit conversions can be found using the syntax:

```
<amount> <unit1> in <unit2>
```

As in:

> [1 GBP in USD](http://www.google.com/search?q=1+GBP+in+USD)

or:

> [0 C in F](http://www.google.com/search?q=0+C+in+F)

or:

> [1 in in cm](http://www.google.com/search?q=1+in+in+cm)

Comment: I like that it works with arithmetic calculations and complicated units too:

"10000 pounds/year in dollars/month"

"(2pi) kilowatt * 3 hours in calories"

Comment: also using "to" seem to work e.g. "1GBP to USD"

Comment: you can also do "1 GBP = ? USD".

Comment: 1 hellameter = 1.0 × 10^27 meters  
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=0h&oq=hella&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGIH_enUS249US250&q=hellameters+to+meters

Comment: (1.21 gigawatts) / (88 mph) = 30,757,874 newtons.  Complete guide - http://www.google.com/help/calculator.html.

Answer (score 59):

### Time

Search for "time in " and you'll get the local time for that place.

For example:

> [time in Detroit](http://www.google.com/search?q=time+in+Detroit)

Comment: also works: `Detroit time`, and slightly less verbose

Comment: also: `what time` gives local time

Answer (score 56):

### Translation

You can use it as a translator ( or as shortcut to translate.google.com )

ie:

translate:Hola to:English

Yields:

[translation result http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8797/capturadepantalla201007.png](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8797/capturadepantalla201007.png)

Very handy

Comment: This does work without colons: "translate hola to english"

Comment: yesss +1, it works without colon too but: explicit is better then implicit ;-)

Answer (score 50):

### define:

I like:

define:*term*

Which finds definitions.Though, Google recently added displaying definition automatically for single-word searches. No "define" needed.

Comment: this is far and away my most used feature of google (after search of course)!

Comment: I'd like to know how Google decides which pages to index as definitions: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/

Answer (score 47):

### filetype:

To search by specific file types:

```
"search term" filetype:pdf
"search term" filetype:doc
```

Two additional things that are less obvious about it (and other specs you can do like it):

1. You can combine 2 or more `filetype:ext` specs
2. You can use not filetype by using `-filetype:ext`

For example:

`-filetype:pdf filetype:doc resume` will find resumes that are in DOC format but not PDF.

`c++ -site:experts-exchnage.com -site:some_other_bad_site.com`

Comment: yeah, and then add some terms to find directory listings *wink* *wink*

Comment: This could be done through advance search

Comment: This used to be an awesome way to search for mp3's, until spammers flooded their index for these searches.

Answer (score 41):

### Fill in the Blank (*)

Sometimes the best way to ask a question is to get Google to fill in the blank by adding an asterisk (*) at the part of the sentence or question that you want finished into the Google search box. For example:

> [Madame Curie died in *](http://www.google.com/search?q=Madame+Curie+died+in+%2a)

Comment: [Dup](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/798#798)

Comment: The first result I get is: 

**Live streaming Slovakia vs Slovenia | Watch Slovakia vs Slovenia ...**
10 Oct 2009... ukraine vs england match, real madrid vs fc zurich pictures, erin andrews peep pictures, patrick swayze funeral, Madame Curie died in *, ...

Not sure that I would call that a good result.

Comment: The right answer (both location and year) come later on the first page, correctly highlighted even.

Comment: Surround with quotes for best results. Then it looks for the exact phrase - and fills in the blank.

Comment: "Madame Curie died" yields better results (first hit is a special one).

Answer (score 34):

### Spell Checking

The spellchecker. Google claimed at a talk I was at that it was the most advanced in the world - I've certainly yet to find one better. It excels in two areas:

**Drunk typing**

Searching for:

```
dfinhryodmnie
```

Finds:

```
diphenhydramine
```

**Context**

Searching for:

```
cofi shop
```

Suggests:

```
coffee shop
```

But searching for:

```
cofi annan
```

Suggests:

```
Kofi Annan
```

I don't know any other spell checker that does this.

Google's spellchecker is so good for a reason - [here are some of the many ways users spelt Britney Spears](http://www.google.com/jobs/britney.html).

Comment: Funny how the all got the last name right?!

Comment: prittany spears - epic!

Comment: I would like to add that if you're drunk you probably shouldn't be having anything to do with diphenhydramine.

Answer (score 23):

### Flights

If you put in a flight number, the top result is the status of the flight.  It's a direct link to information available on flightstats.com.

Enter AA825 and it will immediately show you the status of the flight. It will show you the gate and terminal when it lands.

No more navigating to travel sites.

Comment: This feature could get a lot more interesting now that Google has purchased a travel software firm: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/google-buys-travel-software-firm-ita/?news=123

Answer (score 20):

### allintext:

[**allintext**](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#allintext): matches only those sites that match every word.

It's good when the cached page says:

> These terms only appear in links
>   pointing to this page

Answer (score 18):

### Tracking numbers

If you have a package tracking number from the USPS, UPS or FedEx, simply plug it into Google Search and they'll provide a convenient link for you.

For example:

- USPS: http://www.google.com/search?q=1Z9999W99999999999
- UPS: http://www.google.com/search?q=1Z+8A5+E94+03+4210+396+2

Sorry, I don't know how FedEX numbers are formatted and I can't find a working sample online. However, I think it works.

Also try to lookup a UPC number:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=073333531084

Or an ISBN (Thanks @Joe White):

- http://www.google.com/search?q=0060930314

Comment: This works with Royal Mail in the UK too.

Comment: Related to UPCs: they do ISBNs too.

Answer (score 17):

### Movies

Searching for movies using your zip-code, as in:

movies: 90210

"movies near [town or place]" is a pretty good search. It lets you search for movies playing near a town or place and shows what times they're playing and film ratings and everything

movies near chichester, uk

Comment: It doesn't seem to work outside the USA.

Comment: @Kinopiko: That's not unsurprising. Unfortunately, I can't test from here to see if there's an alternative.

Comment: Works in Canada too.

Comment: You can also put a city/country name (like "movies: paris, france") to get similar results.

Answer (score 17):

### OR operator

The **OR** operator will find pages that have either keyword, but not both:

> joe satriani OR bonamassa

Being a programmer, I once created an **OR** condition as you would find it in programming languages. I was surprised to find this works as well:

> joe (satriani|bonamassa)

Comment: Up vote strictly for Mister Bonamassa. Queuing that on the iPod now.

Answer (score 16):

### Negation / Exclude Terms

Examples

Exclude experts-exchange from my search results using the 'site:' tag, like this:

```
how to load a file php -site:experts-exchange.com
```

Searches for "apple" where word "tree" is not used.

```
apple -tree
```

Answer (score 11):

### Weather Forecasts

```
<CITY> forecast
```

Gives a nice box like this one:

[image: Las Vegas Weather]

Answer (score 10):

Believe it or not, you can insert the letter 'l.' ([ICAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICAO_spelling_alphabet) 'Lima') before 'google.com' in the URL of Google or any subdomain and get to the same site, e.g.:

[video.l.google.com](http://video.l.google.com)

[mail.l.google.com](http://mail.l.google.com)

It might seem trivial, but it has a couple uses: for one, you can go to the site logged out without any cookies set.  For another, you can still watch videos even if your filter blocks video.google.com. :D

Answer (score 7):

### Public Data

To see trends for population and unemployment rates of U.S. states and counties, type `population` or `unemployment rate` followed by a state or county. For example: [population germany](http://www.google.com/search?q=population+germany)

Answer (score 7):

To look up any English word, we can try this:

```
en:en camouflage
```

It will give you dictionary-style definition of camouflage. You can click more at the end of definition to navigate to Google dictionary to see full entry.

Comment: Or, you can do `define:camouflage`.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/support/bookmarks/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174971) and [Stars in search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=176057) to limit my search to a subset of sites.

For example, I have a collection of good bookmarks called [Bash Shell Scripting Resources](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!threadID=GyFDMUuIfY2U%2FBDQ2OggoQ8sqB0ZEl) (It's public, check it out). When I search for Bashisms, these sites are given priority in my search results.

And since I'm using Google Bookmarks, these bookmarks appear in my Google Toolbar or as an applet at https://www.google.com/ig .

Answer (score 6):

Search for 'e' and you get e = 2.71828183

'pi' gives pi = 3.14159265

'phi' gives the golden ratio = 1.61803399

'G' gives gravitational constant = 6.67300 × 10^{-11} m^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2}

And so on for other mathematical and physical constants.

Answer (score 5):

### related: Related Search

To search for web pages that have similar content to a given site, type `related:` followed by the website address into the Google search box. For example: [related:www.cnn.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=related%3Awww.cnn.com)

Comment: just try this keyword: **related:www.google.com** you get yahoo and other sites:)

Comment: This is no longer supported. Ref. https://developers.google.com/search/updates#july-2023

Answer (score 5):

That

my-multiple-search-terms

works like

"my-multiple-search-terms" OR "my multiple search terms" OR "mymultiplesearchterms"

Answer (score 4):

Sunset in xxx (For example, ["sunset in new york"](http://google.com/search?q=sunset+in+new+york)) or sunrise in xxx gives you the exact time of sunset/sunrise.

Answer (score 4):

This was also in a link someone posted, but I use it all the time @ work when a site is blocked:

cache:http://www.somecoolsite.com

It doesn't give you a perfect repr of the site, but if you're just trying to read stuff (like answers to programming questions that are blocked by Websense for being in the "Business & Economy" category), it works great.

Comment: Unless of course the Google Cache is itself blocked, as in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I use inurl: and intitle: to narrow down searches all the time, they can be useful if you are looking for specific pages about a topic, rather than a page with the term anywhere on it, eg intitle:webapps could be useful if you were looking for articles about that topic.

A couple of people mentioned * but I found out a while ago that you can include it inside a phrase search eg "i * my job" finds I ♥ My Job, I love my job, and I heart my job as phrases. You can even combine all of the above like this intitle:"i * my job"

Answer (score 3):

I find subscribed links are occasionally very useful, see http://www.google.com/coop/docs/subscribedlinks/faq.html

That's one I use regularly: http://www.google.com/coop/profile?user=008782217800324848333

I have even written one myself: http://www.google.com/coop/profile?user=010177539747046990252

Comment: The links are now 404

Answer (score 2):

To see the weather/temperature for some city
search for: temperature **CITY**

For example, for Mumbai it would be : [temperature mumbai](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=temperature+mumbai)

Comment: you can also type "weather ZIP/CITY"

Answer (score 2):

To download MP3s.

Simply use any file uploading service, and the name of your artist and song and voila.

Works best for artists/songs that are relatively popular. E.g.

```
kanye west site:mediafire.com
```

Returns something similar to this: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=kanye+west+site:mediafire.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

I hope Google doesn't figure out a way to stop this, but it can be very useful. It can also be applied to other types of sites with other document/media types.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

To find mobile area code belongs to which cities use xxx area code, eg: 512 area code.
This works for all area codes in US.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Experimental search

There is a version of Google which makes Google very keyboard-friendly.

It lets you move up/down search entries with the keys j/k (vim-style), open a link with the key "o", and go back to the search box with the "/" key.

Check it out [here](http://www.google.com/experimental/).

Comment: The link returns Error 404 - Page not found.

Answer (score 1):

For temperature conversion, use a form like "30 degrees C in F".

Using "30° C in F" won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use picture to search google 
http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles

Answer (score 0):

### The '?' operator

You can do all conversions.

Currency converter,
1USD=?INR

Celsius to Fahrenheit,
30C = ?F

It is closely related to the calculator function but it's just simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Several features that Lifehacker posted several years ago: http://lifehacker.com/339474/top-10-obscure-google-search-tricks:

1. Make Google recognize faces
2. ID people, objects, and foreign language words and phrases with Google Image Search
3. Find music and comic books
4. Find related terms and documents
5. Remove affiliate links from product searches
6. Use Google as a free proxy
7. Compare items with "better than" and find similar items with "reminds me of"
8. Convert currency, metrics, bytes, and more
9. Track flight status
10. Get the local time anywhere

Number three was my favorite for a while, and because the browser Opera lets you create your own search engines inside of it, you can program these in very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Google to answer questions, where it brings back the actual answer as text (rather than a link to a page). For instance, try:

[When was ie6 released?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=when+was+ie6+released%3F) and you get the response:

> Internet Explorer 6 release — August
>   27, 2001
>
> According to wikipedia.org,
>   wikipedia.org and sitecrafting.com

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty good with sports events and scores as well...

Searching **f1** gives you the qualifying (after qualifying), race result (after the race for a few days) and then the overall drivers results.

It also had similar features for cricket where you could type **Aus V NZ** to see the current match scores when Australia play New Zealand, for example including the last 2 overs summary...

Answer (score 0):

### Punctuation Notes

Special characters and punctuation are generally ignored except for the following exceptions.

**""** - Quotations
*Phrase Search*
`"Captain Crunch"`

**:** - Colon
*Selector for search parameters*
`site:news.ycombinator.com`
`filetype:pdf`

**-** - Dash / Negation
*Used to exclude terms from the query*
`steve -jobs -wozniak -perry`

**+** - Plus
*Used for the exact term preventing similar words*

**~** - [Tilde Operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/820#820)
*Takes the word immediately following it and searches both for that specific word and for the word’s synonyms.*

**Math Operations**

**+** - Addition

**-** - Subtraction

**/** - Division

***** - Multiplication

**Reserved Symbols**

**$** - Dollar symbol
*Used for currency*

**#** - Pound / Sharp
**Used in:**
- **C#** C Sharp programming language, F Sharp, etc..
- Chords, Scales

**++** PlusPlus
*Used in:* C++ Programming Language.

**_** Underscore
*Treats entire set as one*
`+peter_parker` not peter parker, + is used to prevent similar wordings.

If you still cannot obtain what you are searching for follow these questions for advice:
<sub>[How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)</sub>
<sub>[How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)</sub>

<sub>[↑ Back to top of page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

### AROUND() operator

It works like this

```
pizza AROUND(2) restaurant
```

pizza is maximally separated by two words from restaurant in the website text. So it is especially useful to find a word in a specific context.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-use-undocumented-operator-around-improve-google-searches.htm

For searching very specific scientific papers i use it in google scholar quite alot. One should use it with more other operators and words to make it effective, as *AROUND* doesnt work too well with to much results.

Answer (score -1):

I like how one can replace City, State with a zip code.  For example,

This

1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA

Becomes:

1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, 94043

Of course, this is primarily useful when I'm searching for directions that begin at my house or office, as I know the zipcodes.

Answer (score -1):

Mixing currency and unit conversion you can do:

```
1.18cad per liter in usd per gallon
```

The current answer is $4.39/gallon, which should make some of you feel lucky.