# What are the hidden features of Gmail?

Tags: gmail

There is a great tutorial on advanced features for Gmail on the [Become a Gmail ninja site](http://www.google.com/mail/help/tips.html).  (Editor note: Wayback Machine [latest archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120802191317/http://www.google.com/mail/help/tips.html) that shows the intended content).

What are some other tips or little known features of Gmail that you use which help you stay organized, and which do not appear on the Become a Gmail ninja site?

Please only post answers that do not appear in the become a Gmail ninja list, I do not want to encourage a duplicate list of content.

Comment: *Do you have your own special tips and tricks that help you manage your Gmail inbox and increase your productivity? We'd love to hear your practical tips, so we can share them with the world.

Share your tips in the box below, add some information about yourself if you'd like, and hit the submit button. We'll post some of the tips we receive on the Gmail Tips website (www.gmail.com/tips), so look out for yours in the near future.*

Comment: Which then gets posted on the same Become a gmail site

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being voted to be closed.  Yes there is another place on the internet that you can post tips and tricks.  But that doesn't mean that this question does not belong here.  For example there are hundreds of programming sites, yet a question about Microsoft Win32 APIs does not get closed on stackoverflow as needing to be posted somewhere on an MSDN forum.

Comment: It is not that there is another list on the internet.That list has been exhausted. I have printed the entire list and stuck it in my room. I would be more than surprised if someone finds anymore features. Thumbs up to them but in any case if they did I would prefer they sent the tip to gmail tips sections that way the entire GMail community benefits and not WA.

Comment: I voted to close because (a) this isn't a question and (b) if you really wanted to make a poll type question you should mark it as community wiki so people don't think you are rep-gaming.

Comment: Should be Community Wiki.

Comment: @Michael Pryor: I (a) Paraphrased the last line to be an explicit question but still say the same thing, and (b) I made the question a community wiki.  Please let me know if there is some other reasons why this shouldn't be re-opened.  I understand this isn't an ideal question with an objective answer but I don't think this type of question is explicitly not allowed.  This question should be re-opened unless we also decide to close all of the following questions:  hidden features of facebook, hidden features of flickr, and hidden features of Google

Comment: Could you at least add in the edit that someone should check the Ninja List before posting a duplicate ? I am intrigued to see an answer.

Comment: @phwd: Sure.  I made the edit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [see](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search)

Answer (score 11):

**Organize your inbox by placing "+" in your email address.**  Any emails sent to the  email address `example+webapps@gmail.com` will be received by `example@gmail.com`, because Gmail ignores the "+" and anything after it.  However, this "+webapps" is searchable in Gmail.

Using this, it is possible to set up filters to automatically sort emails based on the address that they are received at.  So, you may give websites that will be using your email address primarily for notifications `example+notifications@gmail.com` while you give shopping websites `example+shopping@gmail.com` and have them automatically sorted into the appropriate labels.

This saves both the time it would take to create multiple filters for multiple sites (e.g. one for Amazon, one for Barnes and Noble, one for Woot that all apply the same label to your email) and is a more reliable method of filtering email than using the sender or the subject.

Comment: *Looks at wall with Ninja List* : #3  on black belt : Filter your email with personalized email addresses.

Comment: I use this **all** the time. Especially when I need to make multiple accounts on a single site, but they check if my email address is already tied to an account.

Comment: there are a distressingly large number of sites that believe that `+` can't be part of an e-mail address, but I usually try first anyway.

Comment: It (sort of) works with dot as well in that the . is ignored, so you can use a.bcd@gmail.com and ab.cd@gmail.com both go to the same user.

Comment: @Gary Huh. I had the distinct memory of xyz@gmail.com being taken when I registered a new account for college communications last year with x.y.z@gmail.com available, which is why I had thought the period trick was phased out in an update to gmail.  However, I now see that I can log onto xyz@gmail.com....must be remembering incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome: You can press Ctrl + Shift + V to paste non formatted text into the Gmail message box.  Saves time rather then what I used to do is open notepad, paste there, recopy, then paste into Gmail.