# How to search the internet for terms with special characters

Tags: search, search-engine, special-characters

As I learnt from this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search), Google has no ability to search for special characters. Let's say I want to search for `ss!`. Are there any other search engines that can achieve this? Please do not propose any programming code search engines since this is a general search.

Comment: well the more popular search engines do not preserve punctuation as they use it as operators. I do not understand why you do want to use a programming code search engine if it will do the job. Your only other option is to just use as is for example += ---> plus equals .

Comment: Think of this case: My computer has some folders with some files named as `MM!` without extension. This could be done by a virus or a program. The search results fetched for `MM!` is nonsense.

Comment: What does google have to do with files and folders on your computer? I think with Linux you can search for any regular expression so you should be able to find your folders...

Comment: @mbrochh: I think you misunderstood. Following my example, if somebody has already experienced this issue and posted it somewhere on the net, I should be able to find it. Searching for a similar problem related to `MM!` case should not be impossible.

Comment: Okay I get it now , but it would depend on the situation, if i do `*MM!*` I will get the first hit as Symantec site threat list, where just `MM!` would give millimetre etc. What folder is it in ? is it a program folder a system folder, is that the real file name ? descriptions like these will lead to a better search it still applies to the `+=` case. What are you asking for is localized and will not be able to make a top hit unless more information is placed in the query

Comment: @phwd: I don't know, maybe this was not a very good example. The original question is on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/160334/mm-file-in-every-directory . Anyway, I'll keep an eye on my question.

Comment: I usually try to put it in context. If you're searching for something as short as `ss!` it will greatly help Google if you supply as much information as you can. Also, try putting quotes around terms that need to be found together.

Comment: putting the keyword (with special character) in quotes does not work. is there any other methods?

Answer (score 2):

[According to one report](http://searchengineland.com/google-search-showing-results-for-punctuation-marks-109038) it appears that Google is now allowing for searches for punctuation. No word on exactly which punctuation is included (although a dozen or so were tested) and I don't see information on punctuation *with* text.

Answer (score -2):

I think DuckDuckGo search engine does the search including special characters. See the search for MM! [here](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=MM!).

DuckDuckGo does not, but you can search symbolhound on DDG with !symbolhound

Comment: Not exactly. The first few results include `MM!` but if you scroll down a little bit, there is no exact results. I also tried `xyz#` on DuckDuckGo but it couldn't do it.

Answer (score -3):

Use double quotes—`"`—to wrap the special character.

Comment: I don't have the rep to downvote, so Raju, please remember to _check_ the validity of your answers, before providing them.

Comment: It says right in the question why this doesn't work.