# Search results of "&#160;"

Tags: search-engine, google-search

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)
>   [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)

I tried to search the string `"&#160;"` in Google and did not give any results!! I even tried within quotes, still no use. And when I search inside StackOverflow got few results.

Any idea how to search these kind of string in Google?

Answer (score 3):

Try it without the semi-colon:  http://www.google.com/search?q=%26%23160.  IS that what you're going for?

When you put `&#160` into the search bar, the url gets encoded such that:

- %26 = &
- %23 = #

Comment: Your link gives me required search results because that string combination is unique I think. But any idea why it is not working with ";"?