# Search Engine that Doesn't Ignore Punctuation?

Tags: search, search-engine, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

Is there a search engine that will not ignore punctuation marks (like $ % & ! @ #...)?  I want to search the web for some documentation on some code but Google keeps ignoring the symbols.  I am not looking for a code search engine.  I don't want to find code.  I want to find articles and blog posts about a particular string of code so searching Google's Code Search engine or Git are not helpful to me.

Comment: duplicate of [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters).