# If I need to find documentation about a symbol, what's the best way to search the web?

Tags: search, search-engine, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

For example, I wanted to know what the % meant in this python expression.  It's the modulo operator, but I would have no way of finding out aside from looking in the index of a book or laboriously trawling through documentation.  If I wanted to search the web for such a thing, how would one do it?

```
x = y % 2
```

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25) can be of assistance.

You can also Google the name of the character if you know it ("percent" in this case).

Answer (score -1):

```
python % character
```

on Google always worked for me

Comment: It did not work for me. [Look](http://www.google.ro/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=675&q=python+%25+character&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&fp=14feb0e2ef05e253), nothing about % on the first page.

Comment: Also take a look at this [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1479/8609).

Comment: @Andris - Who said it had to be on the first page? That's the point of searching; to work a little until you find the solution. If I knew the result is on the first page, then I probably knew the result too.

Answer (score -1):

The other option for specific phrases is to simply enclose the phrase in quotations

"x = y % 2" should work well as well.

Hope this helps