# Using Google Search to find what a symbol means without knowing what it's called

Tags: google-search

I was doing math homework and wanted to find out what `⊃` means, so I entered the symbol `⊃` in Google Search.

However, I got no search results. How can I use Google to find out what symbols mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters) and [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23/88)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia often has lovely tables you can find. I simply searched table of math symbols and I got to this page: [List of Mathematical Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

I then took the symbol and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and entered in the symbol (`⊃`) and I was taken right to the symbol.

Comment: No problem! Wikipedia is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

SymbolHound also helps.

It got me an answer when I wanted to know [what  `=>` means in Scala language](http://symbolhound.com/?q=scala%20=%3E). But [your particular query](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%E2%8A%83) got useless results.

Answer (score 0):

From *mathematical symbols* - as in the question, [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) might sometimes help.

This website tries to get [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) syntax from the given symbol. This is certainly not the same as having the name of the symbol, but knowing the "LaTeX-name" can help to find other sources saying something about that symbol or using it.

The site is rather popular, it was mentioned [many times in Stack Exchange posts](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*detexify*%22). For example:

- [Where to find a specific LaTeX symbol](https://superuser.com/q/71585) (SuperUser)
- [Mathematical symbols, their pronunciations, and what they denote: Does a comprehensive ordered list exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18723) (MathOverflow)
- [Resources to learn the meaning of any math symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204339) (Mathematics)