# Search Google for exact string including hyphens

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)
>   [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

I'm trying to do searches on Google (Scholar) like these:

```
in-memory-database
in-memory database
... and so on
```

The problem is, that even if using quotes like this:

```
"in-memory-databases"
```

Google seems to ignore the hyphens.

Is there a way to search so that only results including all the hyphens appear?

Comment: Did section 11 in the following article : http://www.googleguide.com/interpreting_queries.html will help you?