# How to search for '{search text}' on Google

Tags: search, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

I have been trying to do a literal search in Google for text exactly like:

> {example}

I have tried all sorts of ways like adding '+' prefix, including it in quotes, using allintext etc. without success.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible.  Special characters can not be used to search on in Google.  I find this to be the case with other search engines as well (as expected), like Bing, Yahoo! and DuckDuckGo.

The [documentation for Google Search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2466433) states:

> Generally, most punctuation and special characters are ignored in Google Search.

A list of special characters that *are* supported can be found on the same page I linked above.

Comment: Oops, I was hoping for not this, Isn't there any workaround/hacks?

Comment: It would surprise me, as Google most likely needs to use those special characters 'behind the scenes' in the matching algorithm.

Comment: The quote you show talks about Gmail though, not Google Search in specific...?

Comment: Good point, although the search function will be similar.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This search engine seems to solve the kind of problem you're having: 
http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: Great, but it seems the search coverage is quite low...