# Force Google Search to do absolutely exact match

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to do a real exact match in Google?

Quotes or plus do not make it exact.

I'm trying to search for the phrase "offset 0", but the results contain "offset: 0", which is not the same and not what I'm looking for.

I've encountered such a problem with many other queries, too.

Answer (score 10):

Try Yandex. It's a Russian search engine providing the opportunity to search with an exact match as well as other options (for example searching a word by entering first X letters and leaving out last Y letters etc.). A useful article about searching in yandex: http://www.russiansearchtips.com/2015/04/yandex-ppc-match-type-operators-for-best-keyword-selection/

Answer (score 6):

In your particular case it doesn't look possible.

As [Google Search Help](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134479) says:

> Generally, most punctuation and special characters are ignored...

While that bit is specifically about the search term, it also appears to apply to the index as well. It looks to me that Google doesn't store (or at least doesn't search) content that is punctuation.

Even using the [**verbatim**](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1734130&topic=1221265&ctx=topic) tool doesn't help.

I even tried `"offset 0" -"offset: 0"` but the colon is ignored in the index.

Other search engines might do it differently, but I doubt it.

See also:

- [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)
- [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Use search engine dedicated to this problem (exact match searching):
http://symbolhound.com/?q=offset+0

Inspired by [the answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232898/1908192)