# Is there a web application for uploading images that uses HTML5 drag and drop?

Tags: webapp-rec, images, upload

I'm looking for a page I can bookmark that I can click, then drag an image onto, and that's it. Just two steps for getting an image online to post places (like here). Preferably no login necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new site called http://letscrate.com/.

Drag. Drop. Get URL. It's freaking sweet.

Comment: Seems the problem with LetsCrate as opposed to Min.us however is that there's a 200MB cap and seems to be down as of right now.

Answer (score 2):

[box.net](http://www.box.net/) supports drag and drop file uploading, including images. However, you must be logged in first to upload. You can mark a folder as global to allow it to be view publicly.

Comment: Yeah. I just want a url like "abc.com/images.htm" that I can just click on, and drag image too... no logins, etc. Box.net does have a nice feature set though.

Comment: @mike: I don't think you will find such a service since without login everybody could access that "account" :). Many such services have "Remember me on this computer" to ease the recurring work, but without a login I don't think that really works (maybe for an intranet, but not for the Internet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gmail](https://gmail.com) to drag attachments.

Comment: making the answer bold and big does not make it any better.

Comment: Im just following like the other threads. eg. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5151/what-are-some-good-webapps-that-can-replace-desktop-apps 
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/what-is-your-most-used-web-application
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google

Comment: These are community wiki pages that list a service and have a long list of features. Those use bold and big letters to make the site easily scanable. This is definitely not needed here.

Comment: Neo, this is how community members are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this today. And remembered seeing this question. [Dropmocks](http://www.dropmocks.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few new services like this popping up. Try [Minus](http://min.us/) as well.