# Interesting ways to use Google

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden features of Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google)

In what way that differs from its main purpose do you use Google in your everyday life?

For example, to check if I use a word combination properly I enclose it in quotes and check the number of matches. Or if you have some signature with name and surname and you don't know where is what you can use the search engine by comparing the number of results for each part of the signature (I know that it cannot always work, but generally should be ok).

Comment: It might be worth leaving this as a closed duplicate. The wording is different enough to make it useful when searching.

Answer (score 5):

I use it to see how popular I am (with my real name or my online alias).

With the advent of Facebook, I find my popularity is dropping, but as I get older, that's quite all right with me!

Answer (score 2):

Spellcheck, directions, the answer to life, the universe, and everything, the list goes on...

(Seriously!  Put "what is the answer to life the universe and everything" into google.)

Answer (score 0):

Currency, metric, and all sorts of other conversions work well on Google.

eg. [Weight conversion](http://www.google.com/#q=75kg+in+lbs)