# Search tips and tricks

Tags: search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden features of Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google)

I know of a few good tricks to search the web:

1. Use the most appropriate search
   engine (Google vs WolframAlpha, for
   example) Use it extensively, and
   when that fails, post question at
   the most **appropriate** place.
2. Search in different languages (that
   you understand) Use the special
   "something:" keywords (like
   site:perdu.com)
3. Start searching with
   general terms, then eliminate
   pollution with the - symbol (eg yard
   -school)
4. Start searching with very specific terms, then broaden the
   result set by removing certain
   keywords which seem to be too
   precise.
5. Keep track of closest
   results in case they may later on
   lead to the result you're looking
   for.

Any other tricks out there?

by the way, I was prompted to post this question upon looking for a painting for which I have nothing but a mental picture. I still haven't found it.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google

Answer (score 1):

- Phrase search ("")
- Search within a specific website
  (site:)
- Terms you want to exclude (-)
- Fill in the blanks (*)
- Search exactly as is (+)
- The OR operator

Punctuation that is not ignored:

- Punctuation in popular terms that have particular meanings, like [ C++
  ] or [ C# ] (both are names of
  programming languages), are not
  ignored.
- The dollar sign ($) is used to indicate prices. [ nikon 400 ] and [
  nikon $400 ] will give different
  results.
- The hyphen - is sometimes used as a signal that the two words around
  it are very strongly connected.
  (Unless there is no space after the -
  and a space before it, in which case
  it is a negative sign.)
- The underscore symbol _ is not ignored when it connects two words,
  e.g. [ quick_sort ].

Sources:

[Google search basics: Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35890) and

[Google search basics: More search help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861).

Comment: I've edited the links back in as the references are still useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the image search I recommend Google (http://images.google.com/). It does a nice job of matching the keywords with the image. Also, use the filters(type, size, color) to narrow down to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I often encounter when a search becomes difficult: I don't know the exact spelling, or I don't know the common term the thing I look for usually is referred. So I try to think of something related. For instance I recently was searching for a german entrepreneur who is popular for his social engagement towards his employees but I totally forgot his name and the name of his company. But I remembered him from a Youtube Video, there he flew with a helicopter, so my successful search term (in german) was a after experimenting with a few terms: textile employees entrepreneur social helicopter

Another tip: Switch search engines and use other web pages as search engines by reading them or using STRG-F. For instance you know how to get near the topic. Use the above method but afterwards click on some links and read them. Think about the content and ask yourself: Is this kind of web page more close to the result I am looking for than the web page (result page) I was browsing before? Yes? So change your search term and incorporate terms or "figures of speech" shown on this page. You will probably get to a similar page that might be even more relevant.

If you are looking for video content it makes sense to search on Youtube. But beware: Google search is better ;) So consider the last described tip and switch between Youtube and Google. For instance once I was looking for a funny video of some guy. After some "switching" I found his name, continuing I found the name of documentary and finally I got the video clip I was looking for...

By the way regarding this painting: If you are still not successful on Google, try to find a forum of art enthusiasts that might know this painting. That way I once found a song very quickly. (Though I already knew the forum, though I never used it before...)