# How can I make Google Search default for all words with "allintext:"?

Tags: google-search

There is a hidden search option for Google to search for all words on the result page:
 [`allintext:`](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#allintext). (See: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1095/27469)

Is there a possibility to add this option to all Google searches by default?

Maybe as a Firefox plugin or a Greasemonkey script?

Comment: Questions asking for a software recommendation like a Firefox plugin are off-topic here, but they might be asked in [softwarerecs.se]. Questions about how to develop a plug-in are off-topic here, but they might be asked on [so]. Questions about using a specific web browser feature and web browser extension like Firefox and Greasemonkey in general, are off-topic here but might be asked in [su], and probably also on [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se].  Questions about how to write a specific user script might be on-topic here if they might be managed by as user defined function.

Comment: General JavaScript and complex user scripts are better suited for [so]. Questions about adding a custom search engine might be on-topic but should be specific about one web browser and search engine. This kind of questions might be also on topic in [su].

Answer (score 3):

You can add a search engine in chrome using the string:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=allintext:%s`

Then make it default.

Everything that you'll search in the address bar or right click will be `allintext`.
[image]

Comment: would that work in firefox too?  
Or maybe an OpenSearch Plugin for Firefox?

Comment: It works in chrome. I had to search in Preferences and there click on anavanced at the bottom. There I could add this

Comment: I'd add that you should not use "google.com" as a keyword when you add this search, as it appears to add it, but does not.