# How to search a string which includes "$" in Google

Tags: google-search, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)

I want to search this string in Google
'IPC$'

But Google always removes the $, even if I try to search with a quotation "IPC$".
How do I do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can't.](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134479) From the Google Basic Search Help:

> Generally, punctuation is ignored, including @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters.

The only exceptions are when the dollar sign indicates a price or is part of a well known phrase with specific meaning.