# How to you use a * in a Google search question?

Tags: google, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)

I wanted to search for the phrase    asterisk44asterisk (with the asterisk replaced by * of course)  but cannot do this in Google.

The asterisk characters are skipped.

Does anybody know how to use an asterisk in your question ?

Comment: See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search

Answer (score 2):

[Google Search Help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=136861&rd=1)

> The `*`, or wildcard, is a little-known feature that can be very powerful. If you include `*` within a query, it tells Google to try to treat the star as a placeholder for any unknown term(s) and then find the best matches.
>
> For example, the search `[ Google * ]` will give you results about many of Google's products. [...] The query `[ Obama voted * on the * bill ]` will give you stories about different votes on different bills.
>
> **Note that the * operator works only on whole words, not parts of words.**

So therefore, it doesn't work the way you expect it.

Comment: Yes I thought it was treated as a wild card. But the question remains: how can you search for a phrase containing a * ? Is there a \* or /* way , some how ? Something I didn't try yet ?

Comment: Nope, you unfortunately can't search for special characters (it's somewhere in the Help too). See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search