# How do I find on the Internet hits for a word with a dash in the middle?

Tags: search, search-engine, special-characters

Background: I tried to find information about the tool python-config, but a Google search brought up mainly hits for python's config module.

Digging a bit deeper, the issue is that Google treats the character "*-*" in search terms as a stop character and word separator. So even with a Google Advanced search I was not able to find only pages contain "*python-config*" (with the dash). Then I tried briefly Bing and Yahoo with no more success.

On this site here I found [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search), but the search engine suggestions contain mainly code search sites.

So my question remains: **How do I find with Google hits for a word with a dash in the middle, e.g. "*python-config*". What is the best way to do this?**

ps: Meanwhile I did find out what the python-config tool is for - by reading through the python.org documentation, but not by *searching* the python.org site, because it uses a custom google search...

Comment: Edited the question, so that IMHO it is not a duplicate, but the answers given *here* still apply and are valuable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Google's Verbatim search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1734130) to make Google not to interpret your search terms and do a search as it is.

[Search results](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=python-config&hl=en&safe=active&tbo=1&output=search&source=lnt&tbs=li:1&sa=X&ei=AhjXTq-fCYqM8gPen_37DQ&ved=0CBUQpwUoBw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=358262202b90754&biw=1404&bih=767) based on Verbatim.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same Google results as with Verbatim mode just by putting double quotes around the term, e.g. search for "python-config" (with the quotes).

This still matches things like 'python/config' but it won't match things like 'config 0.3.7 : Python Package Index'

There is no general-purpose search engine that doesn't ignore dashes.<s>, but in your specific example, which is related to programming, symbolhound seems to do pretty well: http://symbolhound.com/?q=python-config</s>

Editor's note:

There are comments in the SymbolHound post on Stack Apps reporting that it has been down since April 2022. No reply from the developer. Ref. [SymbolHound: Search Stack Overflow for special characters](https://stackapps.com/q/2690/)

Comment: yep, that's exactly my issue: even with quotes i cannot search for the dash. thanks for clarifying this. i guess google cannot do it at all ("what's not indexed, can't be searched on."), so my question stands: is there an internet search engine which allows me to search on dashes?