# How does Google handle special characters?

Tags: google-search, special-characters

According to Google [Basic search help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479)

> Generally, most punctuation and special characters are ignored, however there is a [growing list of punctuation](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) and symbols that are recognized in searches.

How are the symbols not mentioned in that list handled? I thought that the search is the same as if they were replaced by space, but experimenting with some search queries suggest that this is not true. For example, ["x^x" integral](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22x%5Ex%22+integral) returns completely different results than ["x x" integral](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22x%20x%22+integral). (And the first query gives several results that contain the character ^.)

Comment: Are you interested in '^' specifically or every other special character? I think the answer varies.

Comment: Personally I am mostly interested in symbols which might be used when searching for mathematical expressions; but let's keep this question general (and consider the example with ^ only as an illustration of the more general thing). If needed, I can still post a follow-up question about something more specific.

Comment: There's an interesting thread about this on SO including reference to the specific situation you referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters

Comment: Related: [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in google search?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)