# Is there a search engine that allows you to search for a specific string including special characters that has similar coverage to Google

Tags: search, search-engine, special-characters

Let's say I want to search for *"100-Coins Star"* (with the speech marks to tell Google to search for that specific term).

Google comes up with results for *100 Coins Star*.
Ignoring the spaces and dash.

Is there a way to get Google to behave they way I want it to. Or is there a site that does allow this and has similar coverage to Google?

Comment: Related: [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23)

Comment: @Krampus. Duck duck go and symbol hound don't have nearly the amount of coverage as google.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google doesn't allow that, the hyphen or dash is part of its [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861). However, having your search query between quotation marks does strongly indicate that you want that expression found as a continuous block. And the hyphens in between might also add to the relevance of the search, like for "devil-may-care".

I don't know of any search engines that favors match over relevance.