# Search the web for a long hyphen "–" but exclude items with a short hyphen "-"

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I would like to search for a word that is preceded by a long hyphen "–" (`U+2013 : EN DASH` ) such as

```
–format
```

but exclude items that have short/normal/minus hyphen "-": (`U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS`):

```
-format
```

Can this be done with a Google search? Obviously, it is awkward because the minus sign is used to exclude terms, and it also seems that Google search doesn't differentiate between the two. If there is a way to do it with Google, that would be awesome, otherwise, any other search engine would work.

For example, I tried searching for

```
"–format"
```

but this just brings up a search for "format" although it returns fewer results (still billions though !).

I also  tried

```
"–format" -"-format"
```

with no luck either.

Comment: Have you tried your search with the endash inside quotes, e.g.`"–format"`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes,google seems to ignore the hyphen. "–format" just brings up a search for "format" although it returns fewer results (still billions though !). Also tried `"–format" -"-format"` with no luck either.

Comment: I think that this is going to end up being a duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search.  There are a couple more recent answers there from 2017 that seem to indicate that *some* non-alphanumeric characters get picked up, but it usually requires two or more.