# How to search for exact phrases that include quotation marks

Tags: google-search

I want to search for: Putin "wins" presidential election

I am looking for a site which uses quotes as sarcasm, but I cannot search for phrases that include quotes, since they will be turned into modifiers to my search instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not with Google. Your options are:

- Search without the quotes. If you know that the rest of the phrase is an exact match, you can search for `"Putin wins presidential election"`. You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to speed up the process.
- Use another tool. While not a search engine, [English-corpora.org](https://www.english-corpora.org/) allows you to search punctuation on select parts of the web. For your example, you could search for `" wins "` (the spacing is important).

I wasn't able to find a match for your search using either of these methods, however, so an exact hit may not be out there for this search.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching `site which uses quotes as sarcasm`

Between the results there were included :

> [Feeling Witty? These 200 Sarcastic Quotes Ensure ... - Parade](https://parade.com/1079501/stephanieosmanski/sarcastic-quotes/)
>
> Nov 1, 2022 — Here are the 200 best sarcastic quotes, from funny comments, sayings, and phrases dripping with snarky sarcasm.

> [250 Sarcastic Quotes and Sarcasm Sayings to go witty - Invajy](https://www.invajy.com/sarcastic-quotes/)
>
> If you are feeling witty and want to communicate your message through sarcastic remarks, here we have curated best Sarcastic Quotes for you. Use these sarcasm ...

As you can see the above are collections or sarcastic quotes. Later your can refine your search by using search operators like `site:`

Related

- [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23/88163)